# .Bat/CMD - Hiding "ERROR" if the key was not found

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, echo

This is my code:

```
@echo off

echo Checking 32bit registry.
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\EA GAMES\NFSMW" /v InstallDir >nul
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto CHECKEND
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto CHECK64

:CHECK64
echo Checking 64bit registry.
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\EA GAMES\NFSMW" /v InstallDir >nul
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto CHECKEND
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto CLOSE

:CHECKEND
echo Registry key was found. Preparing uninstall...

:CLOSE
pause
exit
```

And my question is: How can i hide **ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.** if the key was not found?

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\EA GAMES\NFSMW" /v InstallDir >nul 2>&1
```

and

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\EA GAMES\NFSMW" /v InstallDir >nul 2>&1
```

is hiding that output.